# XUnit Console Runner Options

Tags: teamcity, xunit.net

I have a suite of XUnit Tests in a .NET solution that is built in a TeamCity CI environment. The tests in question generate html templates. In our development environment, they write the results to the Visual Studio console using `ITestOutputHelper`. In Team City, the output is making the build artifacts way too big, and I want to find a way of suppressing the output as it is not needed in the build.

I imagine this will be achieved using an XUnit console runner command line option (but open to suggestions). I have found this list of command line options fsharp/FAKE#759, but it doesn't include one to suppress output. Is there any other (configuration-based) way of achieving what I want? (There are a lot of test classes and I don't want to have to refactor them all).